# Get Listbox item text by index value

Tags: c#, listbox

I want to obtain listbox text by index value
Heres the code to get item text

```
string text = lboxSymbol.GetItemText(lboxSymbol.SelectedItem);
```

Comment: Please include what behavior you expect and how the behavior you are seeing is different from what you expect.

Comment: What's your problem. You mentioned what you want to do. It seems correct. You didn't mention your problem

Comment: hello , i wana run my listbox items in a for loop but i need use text of index instead index , for example my listbox index 1 is testname and i wana get testname to a string i hope you can understand my mean . sorry for bad english btw

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < lboxSymbol.Items.Count; i++) { MessageBox.Show($"item #{i + 1} is: {lboxSymbol.Items[i].ToString()}"); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
string text = lboxSymbol.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

This will output the text of the selected listbox item when it is used.
For example:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string text = lboxSymbol.SelectedItem.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(text);
}
```